A map for $(d+1)$-tuples of permutations from $S_{d+1}$
Let $d \ge 1$ be a natural number and let $S_{d+1}$ denote the symmetric group on the set $\left\{0,1,\ldots,d\right\}$.
Given $d+1$ permutations $\pi_0,\pi_1,\ldots, \pi_d$, i.e. $\pi_k \in S_{d+1}$
define
$\sigma_m(k) := \begin{cases}
  \pi_{\pi_m^{-1}(k)}^{-1}\pi_m^{-1}(m), & k \ne m \\\\
  \pi_k^{-1}(k), & k = m
\end{cases}$
Suppose for all $0 \le m_1, m_2, k \le d$ we have a "column condition"
$\sigma_{m_1}(k) = \sigma_{m_2}(k)$.
I wonder if it can then be shown that for all $0 \le k_1, k_2 \le d$ we have a "row condition"
$\sigma_{0}(k_1) \ne \sigma_{0}(k_2)$ with $k_1 \ne k_2$.
i.e that $\sigma_0$ itself can be interpreted as a permutation from $S_{d+1}$.
Using brute-force methods shows, that this works at least for $d=1,2,3,4$.
So if there does exist a counter-example, we need at least $d\ge 5$.
Here are two text files for d=2:
mse-4969381-cycle2d.txt 
mse-4969381-cycleinv2d.txt 
The first file shows all possible $\pi_k$ tuples in cycle notation.
followed by the matrix $\sigma_{mk} := \sigma_m(k)$.
The second file shows the inverted $\pi_k$ instead.

Is there any motivation behind your definition of $\sigma_m$? And what is the statement right after its definition supposed to mean?

I was trying to construct some test code for a numerical subdivision scheme.
Where the $\pi_k$ needed to satisfy some equations depending on a single parameter permutation. The definition for the $\sigma_m$ was the one who recovered that single parameter permutation from a given solution $(\pi_0,\ldots,\pi_d)$.

If I understand your definition correctly, the statement is already wrong for $d=2$: Consider $\pi_0=(0)(1)(2)$, $\pi_1=(0)(12)$ and $\pi_2=(012)$. Then we should have
$$\sigma_0(0) = \pi_0^{-1}(0) = 0$$
and
$$\sigma_0(1) = \pi_{\pi_{0}^{-1}(1)}^{-1}(\pi_{0}^{-1}(0)) = \pi_{1}^{-1}(0) = 0$$

I have clarified, see my edit, that the column condition should imply the row condition. So $m$ essentialy is a row and $k$ a column index for me, for a matrix defined by $\sigma_m(k)$. Your supposed counter-example is invalid, because it doesn't satisfy the column condition, because of $\sigma_0(0) = 0 \neq 2= \sigma_1(0)$.

I have added two text files for $d=2$. A valid example can be found e.g. at line 711.Your invalid counter-example can be found at line 46.
